# How to integrate DSM elevation values into a classification scheme?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, classification

I'm in the process of attempting to create a corrected DTM for a UAV flight of a salt marsh. As part of this process I'm trying to integrate mean elevation values from each cell of a raster DSM into my classification criteria. I'm performing an SVM classification using OrfeoToolbox plugin in QGIS. I used a high-resolution orthophoto to successfully perform my segmentation and have generated zonal statistics for each segment.

I'd like to merge the raster elevation cell values with this data, but how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have, I believe, two options. First you can run GDAL utility `gdal_merge`, from the processing toolbox (Also appears under the `Raster->Miscellaneous` menu). You should check the "Place each input file into a separate band" option.

Alternatively, just build a virtual raster (vrt) from the two rasters and use that in your segmentation procedure. Again you need to check the option "Place each input file into a separate band".

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked for me.